# How to set image as wallpaper from URL by clicking a button?

Tags: java, android, textview, imageview, drawable

i am currently a beginner android developer, i am creating a wallpaper app. I do not want to use the png drawable images because it will eat too much space and also will badly influence user experience so, i want to get png wallpaper images from a url when someone clicks on a button. I have searched on google for this but there are very huge codes. Can anyone can tell me the easy way?. I also want to show the wallpaper test images with URL in the app

Comment: Checkout Picasso library for Android you can display picture from url into your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try Glide library for Android.

Answer (score 0):

by using glide library or wallpaper manager implement this code on click listener.

```
        Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile( wallpapers.get(i).getImageURL());
                WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);

                try {
                    manager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Listo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```